# "Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file"

Tags: apt

I added a third party repository and now I'm seeing this warning while updating my packages list:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://codezen.org/debian/dists/sid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two causes but in your case is that you have configured multiarch to ask for i386 packages while that repository is amd64 exclusive. The same would be happened if you set arm64 or any other architecture as foreign architecture with dpkg.

There are three ways to go:

1. If the repository should have amd64 packages, contact the maintainer and let them know.
2. If you actually don't want/need foreigns architectures installed on your system you can disable them with `dpkg --remove-architecture`.
3. You can set your `sources.list` to only ask for the architecture the repository is supposed to provide, so apt doesn't try to ask for them. Something like this:

   ```
   deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://codezen.org/debian sid main
   ```

---

### Other causes

This can also happen if components (main, contrib, security, etc.) or type of packages (sources vs binaries) aren't available in the repository. This can be identified by the string `main/binary-i386/Packages`. Here, `main` is the component, and `binary` the type of package, `i386` the architecture.